# Is there an easy way to delete a complete Vespa document set?

Tags: vespa

Playing with Yahoo's [vespa.ai](http://vespa.ai/), I'm now at a point where I have a search definition with which I am happy, but still, have a bunch of garbage test documents stored.

Is there an easy way to delete/purge/drop all of them at once, ala SQL `DROP TABLE` or `DELETE FROM X`?

The only place I found at this point where deleting documents is clearly mentioned in the [Document JSON format](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/document-json-format.html) page. As far as I understand it requires deleting documents one by one, which is fine, but gets a bit cumbersome when one is just playing around.

I tried deleting the application via the [Deploy API](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/cloudconfig/deploy-rest-api-v2.html) using the default tenant, but the data is still there when issuing search requests.

Did I miss something? or is this by design?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no API available to do this, but the [`vespa-remove-index`](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/vespa-cmdline-tools.html#vespa-remove-index) command line tool could help you out. Ie, to drop everything:

```
$ vespa-stop-services
$ vespa-remove-index
$ vespa-start-services
```

You could also play around with using [garbage collection](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/services-content.html#documents) for this, but I wouldn't go down this path unless you are unable to use `vespa-remove-index`.

Comment: note: this needs to be run on all content nodes. if you are having your data distributed on multiple content nodes.